# Unable to Get IIS Response Times with Hyperic Monitoring Tool

Tags: hyperic

We have a very large .NET application (vendor) that I am trying to gather performance metrics for using Hyperic.  In general I wanted to be able to report response times for each of the components within the application, which include:

- Web Services
- ASP.NET Pages
- MSMQ

I am currently unable to successfully monitor the response times for IIS on my windows machines. I have successfully auto-discovered them and I am getting diagnostic information, but am not getting back the response times. After looking online at what other people are seeing, I found that I am missing a tab for the response times which is usually next to the metrics tab. Also, when I look at the configuration screen for IIS I do not see a field which enables me to specify where the log files are located at. Please note that my logs are located at e:\LogFiles\ instead of the usual location because our IT staff doesn't allocate much space for the C: drive.   Please note that I have the MSMQ monitors up and running great.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature that is only included in the enterprise edition of Hyperic.

Documentation regarding this feature can be found [here](http://support.hyperic.com/display/DOCSHQ32/Response+Time)